# Change header and bottom style in expo router

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

In my `app.json` I have enabled `light` mode by default,

```
{
  ...
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
  ... 
}
```

And in my `_layout` file in app directory I have put `headerShown to false`,

```
const AuthLayout = () => {
  return (
    <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="walkthrough" />
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

This is my walkthrough component where I have put flex:1 and background color to dark,

```
const Walkthrough = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#000" }}>
      <Text>Walkthrough</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

But it showing like this,
[image]

Top bar and bottom bar is white even I have given flex 1,  What cause this? can somebody explain?